# angularfire $bind on change appears to replace the object?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

angularfire's three way binding is replacing the object on "change" instead of updating the object.  The effect is if you are writing very simplistic examples it works fine but in the real world,  you would like to reference that bound object in other objects.  This is undesirable.  For example:

```
    var myComplexObject = {}:

    var fbUrl = new Firebase(url);
    $scope.items = $firebase(fbUrl);
    $scope.items.$on("loaded", function() {
        $scope.items.$bind($scope, "remoteItems").then( function(unbind){
           myComplexObject.myData = $scope.remoteItems;
        });
```

Initial state:  myComplextObject.myData === $scope.remoteItems evals to: true;

This pseudo code will work ( 3way binding functionality ) up until there is a 'change' event ( which could be trigger by remote change ).  Once the change occurrs,  $scope.remoteItems will be populated but now the connection to myComplexObjext is broken.  Hence: 
Post change state: myComplextObject.myData === $scope.remoteItems evals to: false;

Any thoughts here?  Is this a function of javascript?  In C it would easier to implement with pointers,  maybe this is not possible in javascript.  I know that I could add a watch and re-assign but this is undesirable and unmanageable.  As I have created a service that frontends all connectivity to firebase.

If I have missed something conceptually let me know.

Comment: That seems right, if you want more granular control and wish to keep a reference to the object around, I recommend using just the `$firebase` service. The object returned by it is never replaced, but any changes to the data must be made using methods like `$add`, `$save` etc.

Comment: I haven't been able to prove it, but the behavior I'm seeing in my app would be explained exactly by what you are saying here.  Frankly, I think this greatly diminishes the usefulness of angularfire.